# Rebasing a submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repository A, having repository B as a submodule.
In an ideal world this should never happen, but let's say, that for some reason, I want to do an interactive rebase in repository B.

If I do so, and push the new commits to the remote (using `git push origin master --force`), next time I will clone repository A, and call:

```
git submodule update --init
```

this command will fail, because the history of B was rewritten, and git will not be able to find that specific commit the submodule B was initially added to A with.

What can I do?

Remove the submodule and add it again? Is there a better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you said, you force updated repo B, but not update the reference in repo A. So what you have to do is to update it.

Go to the root directory in repo A, then you can use the following commands:

```
$cd /path/to/B
$git fetch   // fetch the newest commit of B
$git checkout origin/master

$cd /path/to/A
$git diff   // if all right, you will see some message like below

  --- a/submodule/B
  +++ b/submodule/B
  @@ -1 +1 @@
  -Subproject commit ac0569b524b9e47e86cb0a6c83e2e64c07fd878b
  +Subproject commit 84f9ac384242ded082feac5eeccfd608e2bab918

$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'message'
$ git push  // push the commit to A
```

After these, you can clone repo A and try again `git submodule update --init`

Comment: What about the older commits in repo A? Wouldn't they still reference the commits from repo B that were made before the rebase?

Answer (score 0):

you want update A/.gitmodules to reflect changes in B. Now in the process of B's force push if you would have lost some refs, update will break.

What is reason to do a force push ?

Comment: I have to do a force push because history of B was rewritten, so remote will not allow to push. My problem is, that when I add the submodule to A, git stores the current latest commit sha1, so next time when I do a `$ git submodule update` it can checkout that commit. However, because of the rebase that commit will not exists in B, so git can't clone/update the submodule.